# How to replace a word with spaces

Tags: cursor-movement, normal-mode

Suppose I have the following text:

```
This is a test of the emergency broadcast system
```

What I want to do is delete the word "test" and replace it with four spaces:

```
This is a      of the emergency broadcast system
```

Currently what I do is:

```
cw<Space><Space><Space><Space><Esc>
```

Is there a built in way to do this, or should I look into writing a macro?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Move cursor anywhere on the word "test" and then `viwr` (the last one is a space). Saves at least two key strokes.

- `v`  start visual selection
- `iw` text object "inner word"  (see `:help text-object`, read the entire section, very useful!)
- `r`  replace
- (space) with spaces

Comment: Ah....I didn't realize you could use the `r` command like that....This is precisely what I needed!!